# Twitter Bootstrap without unnecessary things AngularJS UI

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want use the Twitter Bootstrap CSS without the unnecessary stuff like styling `h1`, `h2` elements. It breaks all my style rules. I'd like to just have the styled AngularJS Elements. Is there something like this out there?

Comment: Can you just link to your stylesheet after bootstrap, and overwrite anything you don't like?

Comment: Yes but this change my ruleset anyway. To much stuff that changes using the bootstrap css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize bootstrap to include as much or as little as you want:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/